# How to control the time of displaying of a figure?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

Now, I am trying to use Matlab for simulating a motion. Here is a part of the program:

```
L=line(x, y, 'color','k','erasemode','xor');
rotate(L,[0 0 1],90,[0 0 0]);
```

Here is my problem: I want the line to show after the rotate command, not the line function, what functions I should use to obtain the desired results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
L = line([1 2],[3 4], 'color','k', 'visible', 'off');
rotate(L,[0 0 1],90,[0 0 0]);
set(L, 'visible', 'on');
```

(I replaced `x` and `y` by some random numbers to make the code work)